# MemoryError saving a very large workbook with openpyxl

Tags: excel, python-3.x, csv

I'm new to `python`, although I wrote `C` about 25 years ago. This is my first program in `python`.

I've been trying to convert a very large (0.5 million lines, 80 columns) `csv file` to an `xlsx file` using `openpyxl`. I have managed to write the excel file, but when I come to save it, it crashes with a memory error.

I'm using `python 3.6 (32-bit)`

Anyone got any hints, please? Any comments much appreciated in advance. Thanks!

Code and error are C&P below:

```
#!python3

import os, sys, csv, openpyxl, datetime, lxml
os.chdir('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

# field sizes are large in input csv so need to increase the size of the field size limit
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

# reading in the temporary working file
print('Reading cleaned file...')
with open('input_data.csv') as input_data:
    dataReader = csv.reader(input_data,delimiter=';')
    inputData = list(dataReader)

now=datetime.datetime.now()
dateStamp=now.strftime("%y%m%d")

newDatadump=dateStamp + ' output_data.xlsx'
# Deletes any old temporary working file.  
if os.path.exists (newDatadump):
    os.remove(newDatadump)

#writes an excel file
wb=openpyxl.Workbook(write_only=True)
sheet=wb.create_sheet()
print('Writing '+newDatadump+'...')

#debugging
numberOfRows=int(len(inputData))
print('number of rows',numberOfRows)

#create output file
for line in inputData:
    sheet.append(line)

print('Phew...')
wb.save(newDatadump)
print('through...')
```

Output:

```
RESTART: xxxxxxxxxxx 
Reading cleaned file...
Writing 180810 output_data.xlsx...
number of rows 551628
Phew...
```

And then I get the `memory error`, and here is it's stack trace.
Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Simon/Network Drive/DATA/992 test python/cleaning a file example for internet.py", line 38, in <module>
    print('through...')
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 365, in save
    save_dump(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 313, in save_dump
    writer.save(filename)
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 266, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 83, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 203, in _write_worksheets
    xml = ws._write()
  File "C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\write_only.py", line 261, in _write
    out = src.read()
MemoryError
```

Comment: Using [StackOverflow model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your question will definetively improve readability

Comment: Thanks and apologies.

Comment: A little more info - If I limit the number of lines read from the csv file, the wb.save() starts working (not repeatably) at around 50k lines.

Comment: For info in case anyone else bumps into this thread, I rewrote the code using pandas and read_csv() with the chunksize option set.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing *[lxml](https://lxml.de/)*, as suggested in the [docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/optimized.html#write-only-mode):

```
pip install lxml
```

That should solve the issue, as it did in my case.

Comment: I'm pretty certain I tried lxml but I think I still ran into problems. From this distance I can't remember whether it was memory or something else. As an addendum, I installed 64 bit python and I could do away with the chunking.

Comment: Used it but still ran into the MemoryError.